# How to change the default snackbbar animation to "Top-to-button"?

Tags: java, android, snackbar

I have setting my snackbar gravity to "Top" but the animation is still from button-to-top. Any idea or reference to change the default animation?

My snackbar Java code:

```
    public Snackbar ShowIndefiniteBanner(String ToastMessage, View view){
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(root, ToastMessage, BaseTransientBottomBar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = snackbar.getView().getLayoutParams();
        if (params instanceof CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) params).gravity = Gravity.TOP;

        } else {
            ((FrameLayout.LayoutParams) params).gravity = Gravity.TOP;
        }
        snackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
        return snackbar;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a working snack bar from the top, just use [this library](https://github.com/AndreiD/TSnackBar). It works.

```
TSnackbar snackBar = TSnackbar.make(your_parent_view, the_text, TSnackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
snackBar.show();
```

But if you want to use the standard snack bar, check the repo and look what he's done.